# What is the difference between prefetch and max_batch_size when consuming events from eventhub using the python eventhub sdk

Tags: python, azure-eventhub

I am using the azure-eventhub python library provided by Microsoft to connect to an eventhub and capture events asynchronously.

Below is the piece of code I am using to connect

```py
client = EventHubClientAsync(ADDRESS, debug=False, username=USER, password=KEY, http_proxy=self.proxy_settings)
receiver = client.add_async_receiver(CONSUMER_GROUP, str(i), OFFSET,                                               prefetch=self.azuremonitor_config.PREFETCH_SIZE)


batch = await receiver.receive(max_batch_size=azuremonitor.azuremonitor_config.MAX_BATCH_SIZE,timeout=azuremonitor.azuremonitor_config.TIMEOUT)
```

I am not sure what is the use of prfetch argument in add_async_receiver function and how does it differ from max_batch_size argument in receive function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`prefetch` and `max_batch_size` are for different purposed.

- `prefetch` is for the purpose of performance tuning. The client would try to fetch as many as prefetch-count messages and cache them locally in a single request.
- `max_batch_size` is used to control the max amount of messages that the receive method would return.

Let me give you a simple example:

- suppose the prefetch is 300, and max_batch_size is 10.
- When `receive` is called, the client tells to service to give the client as many as 300 messages in just one call. And suppose there're more than 300 messages in the Event Hub, so the client receives 300 messages
- The `receive` just asks for 10 messages, the method would return 10 messages and the remaining 290 messages are cached locally.
- In the next `receive` call, the SDK would check the local cache first, if there're enough messages in the cache, then it won't make a service request by returning the cached message.

---

It's worth to note that  azure-eventhub v5 has been GAed in 2020 Jan, and the latest version is v5.2.0

It's available on pypi: https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/

Please follow the [migration guide from v1 to v5](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/migration_guide.md) to migrate your program.

We also provide [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples) for you to start with.

Comment: How can I set the eventhub to receive 1000 requests per minute?

Answer (score 0):

AS per the definition:

**

```
max_batch_size
int
```

**

Receive a batch of events. Batch size will be up to the maximum specified, but will return as soon as service returns no new events. If combined with a timeout and no events are `**retrieve before the time, the result will be empty**`. If no batch size is supplied, the **`prefetch`** size will be the maximum.

Here is the method:

```
receive(max_batch_size=None, timeout=None)
```

You can read more about it here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-eventhub/azure.eventhub.receiver.receiver?view=azure-python

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @mohit for the answer. I had read this in the code comments. Based on this it seems like prefetch is just a default for max_batch_size. Was wondering if it has any other use.

Comment: Yes you are right! By default prefetch is 300 which will supplied if batch size is not defined.